# jQuery - Closing/ Toggling elements

Tags: jquery

The problem I have is that when the active button is clicked it does not remove its active state and hide the p tag

http://jsfiddle.net/5qDY2/

```
 $('.section button').click(function () {
    $('.section p').hide();
    $('button').removeClass('active');

    $(this).toggleClass('active').closest('div').children('p').toggle();
 });
```

Im sure there is a better way to do this but I cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are hiding all `p` elements first, then you are calling toggle on the current `p` element which will display it any way, so your toggle command will be seen like not working

The same for the button add/remove class also

```
var $ps = $('.section p');
var $buttons = $('.section button').click(function () {
    $buttons.not(this).removeClass('active');
    var $target = $(this).toggleClass('active').closest('div').children('p').toggle();
    $ps.not($target).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eatd7/)

You need to ignore the current button/p element from the mass `removeClass()`/`hide()` operations